# Missing the "aps-environment" Entitlement. Register Fails

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, xcode8, ios10, code-signing-entitlements

I'm struggeling with iOS 10 for a few days now.
I had an iOS 8 and iOS 9 apps build with Xcode 7.3. 
Push was working fine.

I updated a few thing and post the applications compiled with XCode8.3.
Add the new UNUserNotificationCenter for 10.0+ devices, add the capabilities un build settings Entitlements appears in my project. Everithing seemed ok.
[image]

I tested with sandBox env. that the push was still working on iOS10 devices. Every things was Ok so I upload the application on TestFlight.

> ios 10 Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement

So I checked again every thing, documentation, tutos, blogs etc... everything was set as it should. but still I get this message.

I tried to build an AdHoc version to test the app anyway, but the registerForRemoteNotification as expected FAILS with this error :

```
Error Domain = NSCocoaErrorDomain code = 3000 "aucune autorisation "aps-environment" valide detectée pour l'application"
```

So I downloaded the IPA Generated and check the content:
[image]

As you can see, entitlements seems to be here, so why this message, and why does it fail on register.

I'm lost on this one, may the community help me !

PS: Apple documentation used : 
[APNS TroubleShooting](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG2)

[App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW6)

Thanks for your precious help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround.
I create a new empty project, en test it all. Every thing was fine. 
So the issue was not because of my configuration but only because of something in the project file.
Actually my project was an old one from XCode 5.0, maybe it didn't like the automatique transition from one xcode to a new one.

So I restarted a xproj from a XCode 8.3 then a imported all the configuration and file from the other.
Now it works...

(I lost almost a day doing this...)